# Proving a definite integral with a parameter is positive

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I "know" by numerical examples that the following integral is positive:

$\int_{1}^{2}\frac{\left( 5-3x\right) \left( x-1\right) ^{1-3q}}{\left(
7-3x\right) ^{q}}dx$, with $0<q<1/3$

I have tried in every way to prove it but I couldn`t. By the numerical examples, the value of the integral should be decreasing as q decreases, reaching the value $0$ at $q=0$.
I would appreciate very much any help.
Thanks,
Uriel

Comment: Absolutely correct! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the integrand as $f(x) g(x)^q$, where $f(x) = (5-3x)(x-1)$ and
$g(x) = (x-1)^{-3}(7-3x)^{-1}$. Note that $f(x) = F'(x)$ where $F(x) = -x^3 + 4 x^2 - 5 x + 2 = (2-x)(x-1)^2$; $F(x) > 0 $ on the interval $(1,2)$, with $F(1) = F(2) = 0$.  Now integrate by parts, being careful with the endpoint $1$ because $g(x)$ is singular there (you have to look at the limit of $F(x) g(x)^q$ as $x \to 1+$):

$$ \eqalign{\int_1^2 f(x) g(x)^q\; dx &= \left. F(x) g(x)^q\right|_1^2 - \int_1^2 F(x) (g^q)'(x)\; dx\cr
&= -q \int_1^2 F(x) g(x)^{q-1} g'(x)\; dx}$$

and note that the integrand of the last integral is negative on $(1,2)$.